# Serverless Lambda Promise with mongoose is not working .. not returning response to client

Tags: mongoose, lambda, promise, serverless

I am trying to build a servreless application, but application is not working as expected.
Let me admit, i am new in this domain. and I don't want to use callback, but want to use Promise to implement the same.

Problem : Response is not returning as expected, it is coming as undefined.I want to get APIResponse object as return to api call.

Note : I am sure i have done something wrong. need suggestion to resolve the same.

**My Database Connection**

```
  
module.exports = connectToDatabase = async () => {
 
  console.log('=> using  database connection' + isConnected);

  if (isConnected) {
    console.log('=> using existing database connection');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  

  try {
    console.log('=> using new database connection : ' + dbConfig.url);
    await mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then (db => {
      isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
      console.log( "is conencted >>" + isConnected);
      return Promise.resolve();
    });

  }
  catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject();
  }

};
```

**My Controller**

```
 const registerUser = (body) => {

    let user = new User({
        userId: helper.encode(body.userid),
        email: helper.encode(body.email),
        phoneno: helper.encode(body.phoneno)
    })

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectToDatabase()
            .then(() => {
                User.create(user)
                    .then(user => {
                        console.log(" User " + user)
                        resolve(
                            ApiResponse({
                                success: true,
                                responseObj: user
                            })
                        )
                    });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(
                    ApiResponse({
                        success: false,
                        responseObj: err
                    })
                )
            });
    });
 

}
```

**My API Description**

```
 module.exports.registeruser = (event, context) => {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
 
  register.registerUser(body).then (obj => {
    console.log(" Object "+obj)
    return obj
  }) 
   
};
```

If i execute it, this stuck at following, and no response is returning back to client

```
=> using  database connectionfalse
=> using new database connection : mongodb+srv://conenct string
is conencted >>1
 User {
  _id: 5f2e5314ebafa83b514604b0,
  userId: 'YWpveXNpbmhh',
  email: 'YWpveS5zaW5oYUBsaXZlLmNvbQ==',
  phoneno: 'OTY3NDQ5MzMxMg==',
  createdAt: 2020-08-08T07:24:05.614Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-08-08T07:24:05.614Z
}
 Object undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.exec()` after `User.create(user)`. You are using `then` after creating user but this is mongoose `then` not Promise. `exec` performs query to mongo and returns a Promise with response. Using `then` before `exec` is for creating complex queries.